# How to create .properties file in Eclipse Luna?

Tags: java

I am working on a project at my university and i need to create a `.properties` file to translate the app to another language. I've been doing some research and found no answer so far, does anyone know how to do this?

I'm using Eclipse Luna v4.4.2.

Comment: You go to a wrong direction. properties file cannot do such thing, the code and library using that properties file does the thing. what app is it?

Comment: @JerryZhang No, in Java, properties files are used for translation. Some code is required, but so are the message bundles.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a blank text file (or drag and drop an existing .properties file into your eclipse project).  Then you can use java.util.Properties to access the properties stored in the file.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("yourPropertiesFileName"));
```

Then access the properties using properties.getProperty("propertyNameHere") for example:

```
String title = properties.getProperty("title"); //assuming I have a title property in my file
```

Comment: I know it have been almost a year .. but thanks for replying, i didnt visited this web in a long time!.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one by using new->file.

Mention name as .property to have the property file created.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for everything, today i finished my project thanks to you !!

I use New->File then created the Language.properties file and everything worked fine.